# Django Syndication Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rss

How to add images to rss feeds, here is my code snippets

```
class ArticlesRss(Feed):
    description_template = 'feeds/city_description.html'
    def get_object(self, request, categoryid):
        if categoryid == 'all':
            return False
        else:
            catobj = ArticleCategory.objects.get(id = categoryid)
            return catobj
    # set the category values
    def title(self, obj):
        if obj:
            return obj.name
        else:
            return _('Latest Article')
    def link(self, obj):
        if obj:
            return obj.get_absolute_url()
        else:
            return global_settings.website_url
    #  set the one by one objects
    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title
    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.summary
    def items(self, obj):
        if obj:
            return Article.objects.filter(category = obj,status='P').order_by('-id')[:15]
        else:
            return Article.objects.filter(status='P').order_by('-id')[:50]
```

I want to add images(article_photo is the field name) to the article feeds, how to add images to the feed?

Answer (score 0):

See the [section entitled "Enclosures" in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/#enclosures)